# Why Laravel/Eloquent single object save() updates multiple records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm fetching a specific record with a DB table using

```
$myTableObj = MyTable::where(['type' => $sometype])->first();
```

Getting it successfully, updating some fields and saving with

```
$myTableObj->save();
```

Surprisingly, this record is updated along with **another record** that also has 'type' = $sometype. What can be done to prevent this? 
NOTE: originally the table did not have the auto increment id field, but I have read in forums that it may make problems in Laravel so I did add it, which did not solve the problem.

Comment: can we see some more of the code?

Comment: How do you test this ? Is that internal testing ? There seem to be a problem with your table schema, could you show the model class ?

Answer (score 0):

Method `save()` working with 'id' filed only.

You can try this

```
$myTableObj = MyTable::where(['type' => $sometype])->update(['something' => 'value']);
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserts)

Comment: this is the opposite of what the OP is asking. He wants only the record he retrieved to be update

Answer (score -1):

I understand `update()` is to update, but, my answer works fine and fits good for update too. Its useful where you dont want columns to be defined once again for update, (sp when they are not fillable, its tested with primary key as condition)

`$myTableObj->save();` basically its for saving new record, if you want to update that row you can update like below code:

```
$myTableObj=new MyTable;
$myTableObj->exists=true;
$myTableObj->type=$sometype;//this is your condition, identify 
$myTableObj->update();
```

I think what's happening here is Laravel is saving as well as updating row.

Comment: update works just as well, I have used this on my own project.

Comment: Call the `save` method at retrieved model do update the model.